# MVC controlling which properties are shown with DisplayFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, displayfor

I'm using MVC's DisplayFor method to show the value of a property. However, if this value is yet another Model-object, then it will include the "ID" property of that object. I don't like that, and showing the internal database ID is not nescessary in my application.

Can I (through annotations or something similar) mark this property as "not included" in the DisplayFor process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not be taking advantage of what `DisplayFor` can do:

```
<%=Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property) %>
```

and let's say that `Property` is of type `User`

Now you can create a `DisplayTemplate` *(~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/User.ascx)* that is strongly typed to `User` and also named `User.ascx`. And since `Property` is a `User`, MVC will bind this `object` to this `User` `DisplayTemplate`.

Which could look like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="ViewUserControl<User>" %>
<h2><%=Model.Name %></h2>
<strong><%=Model.Email %></strong>
```

Now you can show/ hide whatever you want off of the object your passing to `DisplayFor`